# SQL Sleep() syntax for every database type

Tags: sql, database, sleep, penetration-testing

As part of my job (Penetration Tester), I require to work with multiple databases which I need to guess. In order to guess, I use the sleep() command.

My question is: can anyone list here all sleep functions for all databases? For example:

- MySQL is `sleep()`
- MSSQL Server is `waitfor delay`

Or, where can I find this kind of list? I've searched a lot over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

[Postgres:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-DELAY)

- `pg_sleep()`
- `pg_sleep_for()`
- `pg_sleep_until()`